# Discord.py json issue with json file and bet command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@client.hybrid_command(name="bet", aliases=["gamble"],with_app_command=True,description="Gamble away your money or get a jackpot!")
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.cooldown(1,7,BucketType.user)
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id = 1009907559391567912))
async def bet(ctx, amount : int = None):
  if amount == None:
    await ctx.reply("Enter an amount!")
  else:
    with open("economy.json", "r") as f:
      data = json.load(f)
      chance = random.randrange(1, 20)
      if chance <20 and chance>7:
        new_bal = data["balance"] + amount
        data.append(new_bal)
        with open("economy.json", "w") as f:
          json.dump(data, f)
        await ctx.reply(f"You just won {amount} coins!")
      elif chance<7:
        new_bal = data["balance"] - amount
        data.append(new_bal)
        with open("economy.json", "w") as f:
          json.dump(data, f)
        await ctx.reply(f"You lost {amount} coins!")
      elif chance == 20:
        jackpot = amount * 5
        new_bal = data["balance"] + jackpot
        data.append(new_bal)
        with open("economy.json", "w") as f:
          json.dump(data, f)
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0xFFD700,description=f"<:treasure:1013110162489352192> You just won the jackpot getting 5 times your amount! Winnings: {jackpot} <:treasure:1013110162489352192>")
        msg = await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
        await msg.pin()
```

I'm having an issue with changing the value of a json file. I'm trying to change the value of "balance" in the "economy.json" file so when you use the "bet" command you can either get or lose money and that value of "balance" changes. But I get this error `'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`

```
{"balance": 2}
```

This is all that's in the "economy.json" file and I'm trying to increase or decrease the value so when you get money "balance" increases or if you lose money "balance" decreases

Comment: The error message is telling you that Python dictionaries (the equivalent of key/value mappings in JSON) don't have an `append` method. So `data.append` is not a method that exists. Look up how to use dictionaries. Also this is a *lot* more code than you need for a [MRE] of this issue; none of the Discord stuff or control flow logic is at all relevant.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0):

`append()` is for `list` but you have `dict`

You have to do directly

```
data["balance"] = data["balance"] + jackpot
```

or shorter

```
data["balance"] += jackpot
```

without `new_bal`